# Node.js: "require not defined" error happens in only one js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have multiple node.js files in a project.

The server code is below:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use("/routes", express.static(__dirname + '/routes'));


var aws_router = require('./routes/aws')(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


server.listen(8080);
```

Now I have another file `aws.js` in `./routes` which essentially contains database operations

**aws.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
/*more code here*/
```

Now I am getting error 
"`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`" in aws.js file for `var express = require('express');` Why is that? The same definition is there also in app.js where it is all good.

What am I missing?

Comment: When do you get this error? When you run the express app? Or if you hit a route?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra when I hit the route

Comment: I see. Which route, exactly? And do you see the error in your browser? I noticed that you are exporting your route files as static assets at `app.use("/routes", express.static(__dirname + '/routes'));` Which is unusal in my opinion... So now any `/routes` call happening from the browser will preferentially just serve the route file as a static asset. One possibility is that one of your route files are being loaded in the browser which may not support the `require` call.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra yes the error is in browser. The error is in /routes/aws. What should I use instead of  app.use("/routes", express.static(__dirname + '/routes')); ?

Comment: What is probably happening is when you hit `/routes/aws` your route file is being sent to the browser (which it should not) and trying to be executed there and `require` isn't available there. My first recommendation would be to comment out `app.use("/routes", express.static(__dirname + '/routes'));` and see if that works for you. If that doesn't work, you will need to post the full `aws.js` file (or at least the part where `/routes/aws` is defined) to help us understand how routes are mounted there... Showing the code where the route is invoked will also be helpful to diagnose this

Comment: `What should I use instead of app.use("/routes", express.static(__dirname + '/routes')); ?` Depends on 1) The structure of `./routes` folder (does it have in `index.js`, is it made up of many files etc) 2) What you want to achieve. If you want to expose routes, you need to assign a route handler to the route like: `app.use('/routes', function(req, res, next){})` OR `app.use('/routes', require('./routes')` (assuming `./routes` has an `index.js` which exports a function like `function(req,res,next){}` or a `Router`)